# calculate count of values that satisfy two condition in r

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have a large data set where I need to check to see if one of the two values exceeds a threshold; if it does, I need to count it, and if it doesn't I ignore that value.

I have to iterate through several columns, but I run into the issue where my if statement only checks the first value. A simple example would have the columns `id`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`. If `val1` or `val2` are greater than a threshold, then I would count `val3` otherwise ignore. My data set is called `data`.

```
id val1 val2 val3
1  .4    4    10
2   5    5    11
3   2    2    1
4   6    1    10
5   2    100  4
```

My code is:

```
if(data$val1 > 5 | data$val2 > 5){sum(data$val3>5)}
```

The issue is that it only checks the first row. How can I iterate through every row?

Comment: `sum(data$val3[data$val1 > 5 | data$val2 > 5])` ?

Comment: What is your expected result? Please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43002582/edit

Comment: i would expect id's 2 and 4 to be counted but id 5 to be ignored

Comment: @Rick : could you please be clearer ? Do you want to count the number of rows where val1 or val2 are > 5 ? Or you want to sum all the values in val3 if the corresponding val1 or val2 are > 5 ? Also, your example is not consistent since you say that rows 2 and 4 should be considered but in the second row val1 and val2 are NOT > 5. As others have asked, please edit your question and provide an example (with expected output) consistent with your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
with(data, sum(val3[pmax(val1, val2) > 5]))

[1] 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(data$val3[data$val1 > 5 | data$val2 > 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `rowSums`

```
sum(rowSums(df1[c('val1', 'val2')]>5)>0)
#[1] 2
```